# How to get the Shape of the transparent portion of a BufferedImage in Java?

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

I have `BufferedImage` image objects which have transparent pixels. What I'd like to get is `Shape` or `Area` objects which enclose the transparent portion of the image.

Comment: One or more objects? What you want is the [convex hull](http://source.concord.org/swing/apidocs/org/concord/swing/QuickHull.html) of transparent pixels. If there are separate groups of transparent pixels that you want to isolate, then the solution will be different.

Comment: @Rom1 Thanks for the pointer to convex hull, it was interesting to read on this algorithm.  In my case there can be number of groups of transparent pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it that way: treat the original image as an undirected graph whose nodes are the transparent pixels. Put an edge between adjacent nodes on the image (i.e. transparent pixels that are directly above, left, right, below, and diagonal). Find the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) for that graph. Then for each connected component, compute its convex hull. Return a `List` containing each of those hulls, each hull being a `Shape`.